# What is causing my code to be non-deterministic?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I might've gone crazy here, but I keep recompiling the **exact** same code, and get different answers. I'm not using any random values at all.  I am strictly staying to floats and 1D arrays (I want to port this to CUDA eventually).

Is it possible on the compiler side that my same code is being redone in a way that makes it not work at all?

I run the .exe by just clicking on it and it runs fine, but when I click "compile and run" (Dev C++ 4.9.9.2) none of my images come out right. ...although sometimes they do.

...any insight on how I fix this? If I can provide any more help please tell me.

Much Appreciated.

**Edit:** 
Here's the block of code that if I comment it out, everything runs sort of right. (Its completely deterministic if I comment this block out) 
-this is a electromagnetic simulator, if that helps at all:

```
        //***********************************************************************
    //     Update HZ in PML regions (hzx,hzy)
    //***********************************************************************

    boundaryIndex = 0;
    for (regionIndex = 1; regionIndex < NUMBEROFREGIONS; regionIndex++) {
        xStart = regionData[regionIndex].xStart;
        xStop  = regionData[regionIndex].xStop ;
        yStart = regionData[regionIndex].yStart;
        yStop  = regionData[regionIndex].yStop ;
        for (i = xStart; i < xStop; i++) {
            for (j = yStart; j < yStop; j++) {
                hzx = hz[i*xSize+j] - hzy[boundaryIndex];   // extract hzx
                hzx = dahz[i*xSize+j] * hzx + dbhz[i*xSize+j] * ( ey[i*(xSize+1)+j] - ey[(i+1)*(xSize+1)+j] );    // dahz,dbhz holds dahzx,dbhzx
                hzy[boundaryIndex] = dahzy[boundaryIndex] * hzy[boundaryIndex] + dbhzy[boundaryIndex] * ( ex[i*ySize+j+1] - ex[i*ySize+j] );
                hz[i*xSize+j] = hzx +  hzy[boundaryIndex];  // update hz
                boundaryIndex++;
            }  //jForLoop /
        }  //iForLoop /
    }  //
```

where, NUMBEROFREGIONS is constant (8), Xsize is defined at compile time (128 here).

Comment: without seeing the code, we cannot possibly guess what the problem might be.  Do you mind posting some of it?

Comment: What's the code? My first guess is that you are accessing uninitialized memory, which is non-deterministic.

Comment: Dev-C++ is unmaintained and buggy and ships with an outdated version of GCC. You should look into another development environment; there are several questions on SO about this.

Comment: When you compiler are there any compiler warnings (when you set the warning level as high as possible)? If there are these are usually errors there is no reason for code to compile with any warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Well some code examples would help! But this is a classic symptom of un-initialized variables.

You are not setting some important variables (indexes to 0, switches to True etc.) so your program picks up whichever values are hanging around in memory each time you run.
As these are effectively random values you get different results each time.

Answer (score 3):

Is there an indexing error with your simulated two-dimensional array?  Is `ey` supposed to be xSize or xSize+1 wide?

```
   dahz[i*xSize+j] * hzx +
   dbhz[i*xSize+j] * ( ey[i*(xSize+1)+j] - 
   ey[(i+1)*(xSize+1)+j] );
```

Your index treats 2D array `ey` as being xSize+1 wide.  The code for array `ex` treats it as being ySize wide.

```
 dbhzy[boundaryIndex] * ( ex[i*ySize+j+1] - ex[i*ySize+j] );
```

Comment: Okay, this is a **good** catch. Ex and Ey are spatially offset by 1. So Ex is NxM+1 and Ey is N+1xM. I redid it without the size+1 and it looks like that worked. Why does that work? I'm not too sure. But I just restarted my conversion and it looks like that did the trick.  Nice!!

Answer (score 2):

You are potentially invoking undefined behaviour. There are a number of things that are undefined by the C language standard. Some of these cases can be caught by the compiler and you may be issued a diagnostic, others are harder for the compiler to catch. Here is just a few things that have undefined behaviour:

1. Trying to use the value of an uninitialised variable:

   ```
   int i;
   printf("%d\n", i); // could be anything!
   ```
2. An object is modified more than once between sequence points:

   ```
   int i = 4;
   i = (i += ++i); // Woah, Nelly!
   ```
3. Reading or writing past the end of an allocated memory block:

   ```
   int *ints = malloc(100 * sizeof (int));
   ints[200] = 0; // Oops...
   ```
4. Using `printf` et. al but providing the wrong format specifiers:

   ```
   int i = 4;
   printf("%llu\n", i);
   ```
5. Converting a value to a signed integer type but the type cannot represent the value (some say this is implementation defined and the C language specification seems ambiguous):

   ```
   signed short i;
   i = 100.0 * 100.0 * 100.0 * 100.0; // probably won't fit
   ```

#### Edit:

Answered before OP provided code.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking I was doing. But I can't think of an instance where turning a 2D array to 1D would actually cause some of that behaviour.  I did have a i++%n and wondered if that could do it. It looks like what might've been happening was dealing with 2d arrays, both differentially offset in time and space and size kind of messed with my head.  Thank you for the really in depth comment!

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling it in debug mode or release mode? Each one of these have different way how they initialize the heap and memory.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody said without some code of what is wrong we can't help you a lot.

My best gest from what you just explained is that your creating pointers on non allocated memory.

something like this

```
APointer *aFunction(){
   YourData yd = something;//local variable creation
   return yd;
}

main(){

APointer *p = aFunction();

}
```

Here `p` is a pointer to something that was a local varaible in aFunction and got destroyed as soon as it left the function, this will sometime by PURE LUCK still point to the right data that hasn't been written over, but this memory space will eventual be changed and your pointer will be reading something different completly random.

Comment: I think what might've happened, because I didnt convert all arrays to 1D at once, was some 1D arrays were getting the values of the pointers of the 2D arrays when they were accessing them. Because when I debugged I had ridiculously high numbers (10E+9 when they should be 1E-6) Either way, I think I was totally going to memory I didn't want to be at.